# Get the ROI of two binary images and find difference of the mean image intesities between 2 ROI in python

Tags: python, image, image-processing, binary

I have 2 binary images (uint16, [512,512]) there ROI is at the exact center, how can I get ROI of both those binary images(image1.dat and image2.dat) and calculate the difference in mean intensities between those 2 ROI and save it as a PDF in python. Please help me out.

Thanks

Comment: What's your definition of "ROI"?

Comment: ROI for the Images I have  is a square block at the center.[100:400, 150:350]

Comment: Why do you want to store an image as a PDF? It would be better to store as an image...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `[numpy][1]` .Loading and saving the images can be done with different modules. Here I am using numpy, but there are [other possibilities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4516365/reading-raw-imagery-with-pil-and-python):

```
import numpy as np

#Load the image using numpy
shape = (512, 512)
im1 = np.fromfile('image1.dat', 'uint16').reshape(shape)
im2 = np.fromfile('image2.dat', 'uint16').reshape(shape)

#extract the ROI
im1_roi = im1[100:400,150:350] 
im2_roi = im2[100:400,150:350] 

#Get the difference and save to BMP
im_difference = im1_roi-im2_roi

result = Image.fromarray(im_difference)
result.save('out.bmp')

#Get the MEAN of the intensities and compute the difference
im_mean_difference = np.mean(im1_roi)-np.mean(im2_roi)
print im_mean_difference
```

Comment: Hi Thank you, But I have binary image data, do I have to convert them to image array? and how can I calculate there intensity and variance in python?

Comment: Check the new version of the answer. I added one example of loading a binary image (it depends on the format of your image), and the computation of the mean intensity.