# How to find mean value for a given part of an Image

Tags: python, opencv, contour, mean

I have "n" number of contour detected images(frame). I wants to find mean value for the rectangle portion of that image. 
 (Instead of finding mean value for a full image, i need to calculate the mean value for the rectangle portion of that image.)
[image]
[image]
I have rectangle's x,y position and width, height values. First Image x,y,w,h is 109,45 ,171,139 and second image x,y,w,h is 107,71,175,110. 
I get the values using the below code. 
`cv2.rectangle(frame, (x,y),(x+w,y+h), (0,0,255), 3)` 
 I know using "ROI" concept we can do mean calculation. 
So, I referred some links. 
Ex. [Get the ROI of two binary images and find difference of the mean image intesities between 2 ROI in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21486202/get-the-roi-of-two-binary-images-and-find-difference-of-the-mean-image-intesitie). 
But, I have confused with the parameter settings. Can anyone help me to resolve my problem ? Thanks in advance...

Comment: If you need to compute the mean for multiple rectangles in the same image, you can use the [integral image](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summed-area_table) approach to calculate it. It is much faster than calculating the value for each pixel. Even that this is an old post, I think it can be useful for someone else.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There's easier way to get rectangle from an image in Python. Since `cv2` operates on NumPy arrays, you can use normal slicing (note, that `i` corresponds to `y` and `j` - to `x`, not the other way):

```
rect = image[i:i+h, j:j+w]
```

And taking mean is even simpler:

```
rect.mean()
```