# Python moderngl and PIL with big image (14000x9600) only loads red channel

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, rgb, large-files, python-moderngl

I am trying to load big .png files (~10-16 MB, 14000x9600) with PIL. When I load them into a texture I can only use one color channel (I try 3 or 4 and it tells me it doesn't match in size).

The part handling this is:

```
from PIL import Image`
img = Image.open(loc)
maps.append(self.ctx.texture(img.size, 1, img.tobytes()))
```

Anything but 1 leads to the error:
`_moderngl.Error: data size mismatch 134400000 != 403200000`
And of course the decopmressionBomb warning:
`DecompressionBombWarning: Image size (134400000 pixels) exceeds limit of 89478485 pixels, could be decompression bomb DOS attack.`

I have tried removing the upper bound for image size with `Image.MAX_IMAGE_PIXELS = None` but it made no difference.
Any other (smaller) image is able to load just fine, however in another project I had the same issue with a 500x500 .jpg-file. As it stands currently I only get a red-only version of the texture when displayed. Note that the images can be viewed in full color when opened in a viewing application.

Could this just be a hard limit of PIL or is there a way to overcome this? If not, what is the maximum size an image can have?

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4516365/reading-raw-imagery-with-pil-and-python) might be an approach, but I currently don't think it is applicable to my images.

Comment: Okay, fixed it with `Image.open(loc).convert('RGB')`

Comment: It's Ok to post an actual answer to your own question. You don't have to leave it as a comment.